# Function to move one observation to a different column in entire data frame list?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to move observations around to clean my data set. I am having trouble making a function that will move the first value into a row by itself and apply that value all the way down the data set.

| X1 | X2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | D |
| B | E |
| C | F |

This is what I want my data frames from the list to look like:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | D | A |
| C | E | A |

Comment: `df$right <- df$X1[1]`?

Comment: Is there a way to make this into a function to apply to a list of data frames?

Comment: Assuming you have your `data.frame`s stored in a `list` named `dfl`, you could do something like this: `dfl <- lapply(dfl, function(x){ cbind(x, right = x$X1[1]) })`.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a way , you probably need to specify the row | columns in sub setting;

```
x1 <- c("a","b","c")
x2 <- c("d","e","f")
df <- data.frame(x1,x2)
```

to get your desired output following code works with me

```
df_2 <- data.frame(left = df[2:3,1],center = df[1:2,2],right = df[1,1])
```